# Testing for equality of regular expressions

Tags: javascript

I was surprised to see that

```
/a/ === /a/
```

evaluates to `false` in JavaScript. Reading through [the specs](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/?utm_source=javascriptweekly&utm_medium=email#sec-7.8.5):

> Two regular expression literals in a program evaluate to regular
>   expression objects that never compare as === to each other even if the
>   two literals' contents are identical.

Since `===` cannot be used to test for equality, how can equality of regular expressions be tested in JavaScript?

Comment: Go through this **[JavaScript === vs == : Does it matter which “equal” operator I use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use)**

Comment: You're talking about JavaScript, the language in which `[] == []` evaluates to `False`.

Comment: @SivaCharan how is that useful?

Comment: And `{}+[]===[]+{}` is false.

Comment: @Derek but `{}+[]` is `0` and `[]+{}` is `"[object Object]"` ...

Comment: It shouldn't matter which is on which side of `+`. But in JavaScript... strange things happen.

Comment: @TylerCrompton: don't forget `[] == [].length`. [*This question*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/560263/regular-expressions-equivalence) might answer the original question, or at least nudge OP in the right direction.

Comment: There's nothing special going on here - this is expected and logical behaviour. `RegExp` is not a special object, like strings, objects, and arrays - you wouldn't expect `new MyClass(x) === new MyClass(x)` to be true either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a function that fully tests all the relevant regex properties and makes sure it's the right type of object:

```
function regexSame(r1, r2) {
    if (r1 instanceof RegExp && r2 instanceof RegExp) {
        var props = ["global", "multiline", "ignoreCase", "source", "dotAll", "sticky", "unicode"];
        for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
            var prop = props[i];
            if (r1[prop] !== r2[prop]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

---

And, since flags sometimes get added to the regex object with new features (as has happened since this original answer in 2012 - though the above code has been updated as of 2019), here's a version that is a bit more future proof on future flags being added since it compares whatever flags are there rather than looking for a specific set of flags.  It sorts the flags before comparing to allow for minor differences in how the regex was specified that wouldn't not actually change functionality.

```
function regexSame(r1, r2) {
    return r1 instanceof RegExp && 
           r2 instanceof RegExp &&
           r1.source === r2.source &&
           r1.flags.split("").sort().join("") === r2.flags.split("").sort().join("");
}
```

Comment: You haven't checked all flags, only `g`, `i` and `m`. For example, with your function, `regexSame(/a/s, /a/)` would return true. You also need to check the `dotAll` (`s`), `unicode` (`u`) and `sticky` (`y`) properties. You can find a complete list of flags [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Parameters).

Comment: @DonaldDuck - OK, I added those properties.  I'm not sure those properties were documented (or perhaps even supported) back in 2012 when this answer was written.  Anyway, it's been updated now.

Comment: @DonaldDuck - I added a bit more future proof version that will continue to work when new flags are added in the future.

Comment: For what it is worth as of 2019-12-06 Edge does not support the flags property in regular expressions. 


[Can I use RegExp Flags](https://caniuse.com/#search=regexp%20flags) 


The first answer may be a better idea until Edge supports them.

Comment: @DanHooper - Hopefully, that will be soon since Edge is in the process of switching over to the Chromium engine.  I presume that means the Chrome JS engine too.

Answer (score 22):

Here's a case that even covers ordering of flags.

```
function regexEqual(x, y) {
    return (x instanceof RegExp) && (y instanceof RegExp) && 
           (x.source === y.source) && (x.global === y.global) && 
           (x.ignoreCase === y.ignoreCase) && (x.multiline === y.multiline);
}
```

Tests:

```
regexEqual(/a/, /a/) // true
regexEqual(/a/gi, /a/ig) // also true.
regeXEqual(/a/, /b/) // false
```

Comment: Isn't that the same as calling `.toString()`?

Comment: @Eric: No. .toString() returns the exact thing you put in. This uses a predefined order of flags to make sure that /a/gi === /a/ig.

Comment: Very nice. I didn't know about `.source` & co. +1

Comment: @JohnathonArka: Ah, hadn't thought about order of flags.

Comment: You haven't checked all flags, only `g`, `i` and `m`. For example, with your function, `regexEqual(/a/s, /a/)` would return true. You also need to check the `dotAll` (`s`), `unicode` (`u`) and `sticky` (`y`) properties. You can find a complete list of flags [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Parameters).

Answer (score 2):

You can check the types with `typeof`, then `toString()` both regexes and compare those. It won't cover cases with equivalent flags, such as `/a/gi` and `/a/ig`, though.

```
function regexEquals(a, b)
{
    if (typeof a !== 'object' || typeof b !== 'object') return false;

    return a.toString() === b.toString();
}
```

Unfortunately there's no more-specific type from `typeof`, so if you really want to make sure they're regexes (or regex-like) you could do something along these lines:

```
RegExp.prototype.regexEquals = function (other)
{
    return (typeof other.regexEquals === 'function')
        && (this.toString() === other.toString());
}
```

Then:

```
/a/.regexEquals(/a/); // true
/a/.regexEquals(/b/); // false
```

Comment: You can also use `x instanceof RegExp` to check if `x` is a regex.

Answer (score 2):

Compare them using `toString()`, and check their `type` too:

```
var a = /a/,
    b = /a/;

a.toString() === b.toString() && typeof(a) === typeof(b)  //true

var c = /a/,
    d = /b/;

c.toString() === d.toString() && typeof(c) === typeof(d)  //false
```

Answer (score 0):

Answers above didn't consider case-sensitivity. So built upon [jfriend00's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10776682/8385554), the function should be

```
function regexEqual(a, b) {
    if (!(a instanceof RegExp) || !(b instanceof RegExp)) {
        return false;
    }
    let sourceA = a.source;
    let sourceB = b.source;
    const flagsA = a.flags.split('').sort().join(',');
    const flagsB = b.flags.split('').sort().join(',');
    if (flagsA.includes('i') && flagsB.includes('i')) {
        sourceA = sourceA.toLowerCase();
        sourceB = sourceB.toLowerCase();
    }
    return sourceA === sourceB && flagsA === flagsB;
}
```

Comment: I believe you've pointed out a real issue, but the solution is broken - consider regexps like `/\d/i` (a single digit) and `/\D/i` (a single non-digit). While `/i` doesn't make sense in these simple examples, it's clear that a regex's source can still be case-sensitive even if the input is not.