# what is the purpose of the following expression: (a !== a && b !== b) in angularjs code?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've notice the expression

> (a !== a && b !== b)

[in angularjs source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/8a1eb1625c080445ce1e519762e1f2d4fd842b72/src/ng/compile.js#L2598):

```
compare = function(a, b) { return a === b || (a !== a && b !== b); };
```

Isn't the expression always resolve to *false*? what is the reason to write something like this?

Comment: Not for `NaN`. Wait, I'll dig up the dupe.

Comment: @Bergi, got [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22266391/464709), not sure it's the duplicate you're looking for.

Comment: Whatever it is, it's not a good practice and the code is not readable. I'd replace it with what it actually means so to not confuse other devs.

Comment: @pid, the comparison function is probably often called in tight loops and other performance-critical situations. You're right in the general case, but avoiding two calls to `isNan()` may make the difference.

Comment: @pid, my understanding was that those checks are faster and fewer characters than `isNaN`, which is sometimes important for popular frameworks. Not sure if this case is premature optimiziation.

Comment: There's [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25273042/when-does-a-a?lq=1)…

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi and *zzzzBov* Yes I agree. Also, in a minified framework script (such as jquery.js) it may make totally sense. Still, I wouldn't write it in common application code where performance is second to maintainability. I think we all agree on all comments here :D

Comment: Also worth noting that this behaves in the same way [as `NaN`s] for regex literals. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10776600/testing-for-equality-of-regular-expressions

Comment: @blgt: That question you link to seems to refer to a bug in ES3 (sic!) which was that one regex literal always produced the same object no matter how often it was evaluated. This "staticness" was fixed with ES5.