# Approximate Regular Expression Equivalence

Tags: java, regex

Theoretically regex equivalence is a hard problem having naive solution with exponential space and time complexity. But for practical purposes, is there an approximate equivalence measure for regexes?

I'm thinking about generating random strings from first regex and then checking it against the other and then repeat it the other way. Is there a more elegant check available?

Relevant links:

- [Regular expressions Equivalence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560263/regular-expressions-equivalence)
- https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/20401/sub-optimal-regex-equivalence

PS : I want to code the approach in java though general solutions and ideas are welcome.

Comment: Why is this tagged as Java?

Comment: What's wrong with linked automaton equivalence solution?

Comment: @jnovacho can you elaborate on linked automaton equivalence solution.

Comment: Well it's your link. Suppose you read it?

Comment: @damned http://stackoverflow.com/a/560390/892914 this one

Comment: comparing DFAs is not clear in the solution. Am I supposed to check the equivalence at isomorphic level - which takes exponential time.

Answer (score 1):

I think your solution will not work perfectly.

Suppose you want to compare regexes like `".*1"` and `".*2"` ,
With your naive algorithm , it will keep on executing without a halt.

Better you use `NFA` , and minimize it for both regexes.

If you are reaching a similar `DFA` , then you can compare both regexes.

Refer **[this](https://ritdml.rit.edu/bitstream/handle/1850/8712/DNortonMastersProject03-2009.pdf?sequence=1)** for equivalence of `DFA`s.

**One more way I can suggest** :

Suppose let  `S1`  and `S2` be the regexes to compare.
As of I know `S1` will produce a language `L1` (Set of strings producesd by S1) ,
And `S2` will produce a language `L2` .

We can check equivalence of two languages .

Refer **[Deciding equivalence of regular languages](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/106905/deciding-equivalence-of-regular-languages/106932#106932)** for more details .

Comment: You can check DFA equivalence.